# Android BottomAppBar com FrameLayout e CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragment

Estou com um problema na FrameLayout o funcionamento está correto, mas o FrameLayout está com a posição inicial do Top acima do AppBarLayout, conforme imagem:

[image: Imagem do problema]

Abaixo o código da Main, onde está a base.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".Activity.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/containerMain"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorMenu"
        android:theme="@style/CvTheme"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:translationZ="0.1dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_bgbranco"
            android:theme="@style/CvTheme"
            app:popupTheme="@style/CvTheme" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:menu="@menu/app_bar_menu" />
    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="176dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab1"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="106dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/fab"
        android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="16dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:backgroundTint="#ffffff"
        app:pressedTranslationZ="12dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottomAppBar"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Utilizo o RecyclerView para criar o conteúdo da lista:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Fragment.LeadsFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerAdapterLeads"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

A pergunta é qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é que a `AppBarLayout` está abaixo do `ScrollView` (que contém o `FrameLayout`) na hierarquia de componentes. Crie um ID para o `AppBarLayout` (por exemplo `android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"`) e dentro da tag do `ScrollView` coloque o atributo `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` e passe o ID criado. Exemplo: `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout"`.